# what am I doing wrong by passing a prop from the parent to the child in vue if it only works in the template side?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So i am trying to do a basic WebSocket notification system. I am passing the user as a prop from App.vue to the navbar component. it Can be shown in the template but when I try to call it in the script section. it says undefined.You can take a look at this picture, it shows the id shown in the navbar and when I try to console.log it, it says undefined. [image: The picture]

Here is my App.vue "The parent"

```
<template lang="">
<div>
    <v-app>
    <template v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <AdminMenu></AdminMenu>
    </template>
    <template v-else-if="!isUserLoggedIn">
      <Nav></Nav>
    </template>
    <template v-if="isUserLoggedIn">
      <Navbar :user='user.id'></Navbar>
    </template>
    <v-main app>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
    </v-app>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader

import axios from 'axios';
import AdminMenu from './layouts/AdminMenu.vue'
import Navbar from './layouts/user/Navbar.vue'
import Nav from './layouts/user/Nav.vue'
export default {
    name:'app',
    components:{  'AdminMenu': AdminMenu, 'Navbar':Navbar, 'Nav':Nav},
    data(){
        return{
           
            user:[],
            isLoggedIn: false,
            isUserLoggedIn: false,
        }
    },
    created() {
        if (window.Laravel.isLoggedin) {
            this.isLoggedIn = true
        }
        if (window.Laravel.isUserLoggedin) {
            this.isUserLoggedIn = true
        }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.axios.get('/api/user').then(response=>{
        this.user = response.data
      }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
    
}
</script>
```

Here is the child

```
<template lang="">
    <div>
     
    <v-toolbar app dark>
      <span class="hidden-sm-and-up">
        <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="sidebar = !sidebar">
        </v-toolbar-side-icon>
      </span>
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <router-link to="/" tag="span" style="cursor: pointer">
          {{ appTitle }}
        </router-link>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-xs-only">
        <v-btn
          text
          v-for="item in menuItems"
          :key="item.title"
          :to="item.path">
        
          {{ item.title }}
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn flat icon color="primary" disabled>
          <v-icon></v-icon>{{user}}
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="logout">Logout</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
    
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "nav",
  props:['user'],
  data(){
    return {
      appTitle: 'My template',
      sidebar: false,
      menuItems: [
          { title: 'Home', path: '/home', icon: 'home' },
          { title: 'Profile', path: '/profile', icon: 'face' },
        
     ]
    }
  },
  
  created(){
    console.log(this.user)
   
  },
   methods: {
        logout(e) {
            console.log('ss')
            e.preventDefault()
            this.axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                this.axios.post('/api/logout')
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.success) {
                            window.location.href = "/"
                        } else {
                            console.log(response)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            })
        },
        
    },
};
</script>
<style lang="">
    
</style>
```

Comment: Because at time of execution, your created lifecycle hook does not have a user, because your api call has not completed yet. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: so how do I avoid this mistake? do I just call the user API inside the navbar component?

Comment: Vue works with states. Identify which states you have, and make sure your application does something sensible for each individual state. When a prop updates, Vue will recalculate anything that depends on that prop. In fact, that happens for anything in the state of a component. Avoid using lifecycle hooks though, because those only fire whenever the component goes through that point in its lifecycle, and there seems no reason to use it. Instead make sure that your component can handle "I don't know who the user is", or avoid creating the component until you know what the user is.

Comment: Please don't post entire components.  Please just post the *minimum* needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define your user in data() with default values so you should not recieve undefined error Moreover there is no async/await when you are calling api in the mounted state

### App.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
    <v-app>
    <template v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <AdminMenu></AdminMenu>
    </template>
    <template v-else-if="!isUserLoggedIn">
      <Nav></Nav>
    </template>
    <template v-if="isUserLoggedIn">
      <Navbar :user='user.id'></Navbar>
    </template>
    <v-main app>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
    </v-app>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader

import axios from 'axios';
import AdminMenu from './layouts/AdminMenu.vue'
import Navbar from './layouts/user/Navbar.vue'
import Nav from './layouts/user/Nav.vue'
export default {
    name:'app',
    components:{  'AdminMenu': AdminMenu, 'Navbar':Navbar, 'Nav':Nav},
    data(){
        return{
           
            user:[],
            isLoggedIn: false,
            isUserLoggedIn: false,
        }
    },
    created() {
        if (window.Laravel.isLoggedin) {
            this.isLoggedIn = true
        }
        if (window.Laravel.isUserLoggedin) {
            this.isUserLoggedIn = true
        }
    },
    async mounted(){
      await this.axios.get('/api/user').then(response=>{
        this.user = response.data
      }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
    
}
</script>
```